# Why Do Y Electrial DC Fuses Burn Out?

Tags: dc, fuses

I am doing some re-search for my father that works with electricity. He say that his  Y Dc Electrical Fuses start to burn out, a lot. Please Help. xx

Comment: What are you even asking? What is a Y DC Electrical Fuse? Is there some context?

Comment: The thing to note about fuses is that they are designed to work at the the rated current 100% of the time. To blow a fuse means that more current is flowing than the rating. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/how-does-a-fuse-blow-at-its-current-rating-regardless-of-voltage . How long depends on the fuse type but 130% for an hour is possible. As to why this fuse is blowing? Assuming this is not new equipment I would look to what has changed since it was not blowing fuses. If its a new setup it could be wrong type of fuse. Motors and inductive loads need special fuses.

Comment: Karla, I thought perhaps 'Y' was a class of fuse, but I can not find any information about a 'Y' class fuse. Here is a link to LittleFuse charts:
http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/Files/Littelfuse/Technical%20Resources/Documents/Product%20Catalogs/Littelfuse_POWRGARD_Fuseology.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Fuses burn out because too much current is passed through them, and they go open-circuit, as they are designed to do.

If a device is regularly burning out fuses, **the problem is <sup><sub>probably</sub></sup> not the fuses** (It would be worth trying fuses from different sources, in case there are manufacturing issues).

The problem is with the appliance in which the fuses are failing. There is some issue that is causing the appliance to draw more current then it is normally supposed to.